# Jersey adding ?# to response body links

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jboss7.x

I've been banging my head to the wall the last day trying to understand the source of this, but with no luck.

We're in the process of migrating one of our RESTful services from JBoss 5 to JBoss 7.
We're facing an issue we do not know the cause to and hope you would.

We have a base resource which exposes it's child resources (using Jersey).
Since we moved the code to Jboss7, it looks like Jersey is adding a ?# to the resource we've requested and all the rel URIs (child resources) in the response body. for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<account id="xxxxxxx">
    <link href="http://localhost:8080/service/account/xxxxxxx?#" rel="self"/>
    <link href="http://localhost:8080/service/account/xxxxxxx?#/firstChild" rel="first-child"/>
    <link href="http://localhost:8080/service/account/xxxxxxx?#/secondChild" rel="second-child"/>
    <link href="http://localhost:8080/service/account/xxxxxxx?#/thirdChild" rel="third-child"/>
</account>
```

when the actual response body should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<account id="xxxxxxx">
    <link href="http://localhost:8080/service/account/xxxxxxx" rel="self"/>
    <link href="http://localhost:8080/service/account/xxxxxxx/firstChild" rel="first-child"/>
    <link href="http://localhost:8080/service/account/xxxxxxx/secondChild" rel="second-child"/>
    <link href="http://localhost:8080/service/account/xxxxxxx/thirdChild" rel="third-child"/>
</account>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Meny

Comment: Are you switching also Jersey version? Since you're on JBoss are you sure that done by Jersey and not (accidentally) by some RestEasy class?

Comment: Hey Michael, You're right.
Even though we specified to remove the RestEasy form the jboss deployment, context and standalone.xml it still got to the classpath through the jboss modules dir.

Once we commented it out there, the application used only it own dependencies.